# Groovy shell horrendously slow to start

Tags: performance, groovy, windows-7, groovyshell

I'm running the interactive [Groovy Shell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Shell) and it's literally taking **minutes** to start on my machine (a Windows 7 laptop with an Intel i5 processor and 4 GB of RAM so not an ancient computer, just a middle of the road one)

Running simple scripts using `groovy` or `groovyclient` and `groovyserver` takes an acceptable amount of time (several seconds tops) but after running `groovysh` the cursor just starts blinking for... long enough for me to make tea, write this very question and rant about this on Twitter (and still no prompt to write any code)

Tried this with the following configurations

> - Groovy Version: 2.3.4 JVM: 1.7.0_03 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 7
> - Groovy Version: 2.3.4 JVM: 1.8.0_20 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 7

and it's exactly the same.

I'd really like to be able to use it in a REPL style. Has anyone faced and solved similar problems? Can you recommend a different tool for the job?

As suggested in the comments, I ran `groovysh -d -v` to enable debug and verbose output, in hope of seeing what takes such a long time.

### Output of `groovysh -d -v`

```
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.BufferManager] Created new buffer with index: 0
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.BufferManager] Buffers reset
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Parser] Using parser flavor: rigid
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: ?
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :help
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :quit
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :exit
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: import
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :display
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :clear
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :show
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :inspect
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :purge
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :edit
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: .
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :load
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :save
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :record
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :history
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :alias
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :set
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :register
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandRegistry] Registered command: :doc
```

For a very long time, no further output and then the whole rest in a matter of seconds:

```
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh] Terminal (jline.AnsiWindowsTerminal@66f57048)
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh]     Supported:  true
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh]     ECHO:       (enabled: false)
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh]     H x W:      41 x 169
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh]     ANSI:       true
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh]     Direct:     true
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner] Using history file: C:\Users\Tomek\.groovy\groovysh.history
Groovy Shell (2.3.4, JVM: 1.8.0_20)
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[1] for command: :help
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[2] for command: ?
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[3] for command: :exit
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[4] for command: :quit
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[5] for command: import
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[6] for command: :display
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[7] for command: :clear
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[8] for command: :show
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[9] for command: :inspect
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[10] for command: :purge
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[11] for command: :edit
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[12] for command: :load
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[13] for command: .
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[14] for command: :save
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[15] for command: :record
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[16] for command: :history
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[17] for command: :alias
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[18] for command: :set
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[19] for command: :register
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Added completer[20] for command: :doc
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandsMultiCompleter] Refreshing the completer list
DEBUG [org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner] Running
groovy:000>
```

Comment: is starting with `-vd` giving any clues?

Comment: Running `groovysh -vd` results in the following error: `"Unrecognized option: -vd
error: jvm creation failed with code -1: unknown error"`

Comment: just `-d`?  check the help.  maybe its `/d` or some other windowizm

Comment: @cfrick updated with the output, running with `-d -v` now, I'll post the output if it's different in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 3):

After 7 years ... well, here's another suggestion for an answer. I had a similar issue and investigated to find that on startup, groovysh attempts to resolve classes by calling [PackageHelperImpl](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/tools/shell/util/PackageHelperImpl.html#collectPackageNamesFromFolderRecursive(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20Set)). The problem here is that it recursively scans all the subdirectory. So, one reason for groovysh to be extremely slow to start up is that you have a huge file hierarchy underneath the location where you tried to start it. To test this, try starting it exactly the same but in a folder with no child directories.

Answer (score 1):

It could be memory, ensure that no java apps are running first (Java performs horribly when 2 java apps are fighting for memory in windows--it's a total system killer), but if that were the case I'd think groovy would load slowly too.

Another possibility is that your system may be having trouble loading the JLine dll.  To test for this try:

```
Groovysh --terminal=false
```

It will avoid loading JLine-- without JLine you won't get up/down/tab processing so you don't want to run that way, but if you know that this is your problem you should easily be able to find something online telling you how to fix it.

Comment: I did try killing everything except of the console. Besides, many tools I use, including the IDEs and servers are Java applications so I simply cannot avoid them. Running `Groovysh -console=false` yields `Unrecognized option: -console=false`, so does `Groovysh --console=false`. This looks like a variable so I also tried `Groovysh -Dconsole=false`, this time Groovysh ran but took just as long to start as before.

Comment: I guess I'll try profiling the console with visual VM, maybe it will tell me something about what's happening. The last resort is building it form sources and debugging. But I'd need some spare time to do that. Fortunately, this isn't much of a blocker for me cause I can run the window GroovyConsole just fine.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz I'm really sorry, I said that from memory and got it wrong. try "--terminal=false" or "--terminal=null" (tested this time!) I believe they mean the same thing, both should disable JLine. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This time it actually ran the console but unfortunately it still took several minutes to start.

Comment: I just did a quick test. "groovy -e 'while(true);' takes 65mb to run as reported by process mgr, groovysh starts at 126 and goes quickly to 167mb. If you have other java apps running then memory could be afactor. While groovy is launching does windows act extremely sluggish? Are your other java apps responsive?  If groovysh is run before any other java apps is it better or the same?

Comment: Nope, windows behaves just fine, so do other Java applications. I've tried running just groovysh, with no other applications running at all and the behaviour is still the same.

Comment: Then it's not memory-Since it's not memory/cpu bound I suppose it could be a timeout.  Groovysh tries to open a few config files as it launches, I suppose timing out could cause this kind of behavior. It might be interesting to learn that it was always exactly the same time--like 1 or 2 minutes, indicating that something is timing out (file access over a network?)  I've never seen behavior like this and I really can't think of anything else.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help--can't vote myself down but Maybe this will help the next guy (in combination with your eventual solution)